# How to know if the data transmission is finished in NS2?

Tags: networking, ns2

I'm coding in NS2 to simulate a network scenario where N senders send their data block simultaneously to a single receiver (all the data blocks are of the same size:256KB). I want to repeat the behaviour for 5 times, which means, when all the senders finish their transmission, the whole transmission procedure will repeat again, for 5 times in total. As a result, I want to figure out how to know if the data transmission has finished, so that I can start a new round of transmission.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So simple!!!
When you set your connection, you also will say when does it end...
You can simply say when the first round finished then .......... .
for example :

```
$ns_ attach-agent $node(0) $tcp(0)  
$ns_ attach-agent $node(3) $tcpsink(0)
$ns_ connect $tcp(0) $tcpsink(0)
$ftp(0) set rate_ 500Kb
$tcp(0) set packetSize_ 200b
$ftp(0) attach-agent $tcp(0)

$ns_ at 5 "$ftp(0) start"
$ns_ at 100.0 "$ftp(0) stop" # this line is what i'm talking about
```

Did you get it?

Comment: Hi Jenova, thanks for answering. But I think there is a misunderstanding. I know that $ns_ at 100.0 "$ftp(0) stop will stop the transmission at 100.0, but what I want to know is the exact time when the data transmission is finished. For example, the first round of transmission may finished at 38.41 or 42.98 or any time (Let's call it XSec), but I don't know how to figure out the exact time XSec so that i can use $ns_ at XSec "$ftp(0) stop" to finish the first round and start the next round.

Comment: Your welcome... But i think you didn't get how ns workes...In ns2 if you don't say when to stop a transmission it won't stop at a random time or something like that and the transmission will continue until the very end.Here is a sample of 4 mobile nodes : [link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=42475427507593282369) .... Try to comment the stop time of the transmission and see what will happen...

Comment: I forgot to say that comment the "node off", so your simulation could work.